# CSS selector without ID

Tags: css, sharepoint, html-table

I am trying to hide a table row but my table do not have ID. As this is SharePoint code I cannot add ID in it.

```
<td width="99%" class="ms-authoringcontrols">
            <table width="100%" class="ms-authoringcontrols">
            <tbody><tr><td>
                <input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$UploadDocumentSection$ctl05$InputFile" title="Choose a file" class="ms-fileinput ms-fullWidth" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_InputFile" onfocus="ResetSpFormOnSubmitCalled();" onchange="CheckAssetLibMediaExtension()" type="file" size="35">
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
                <span class="ms-error" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_ctl00" style="display: none;"><span role="alert">You must specify a value for the required field.</span></span>
                <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_ctl01" style="display: none;">The file name is invalid or the file is empty. A file name cannot contain any of the following characters: \ / : * ? " &lt; &gt; | # { } % ~ &amp;</span>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
                <a id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_OpenWithExplorerLink" accesskey="E" onclick="javascript:return !LaunchOpenInExplorer();" href="#">Upload files using Windows Explorer instead</a>
            </td></tr>

            <tr><td>
                <input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$UploadDocumentSection$ctl05$OverwriteSingle" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_OverwriteSingle" type="checkbox" checked="checked"><label for="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_OverwriteSingle">Overwrite existing files</label>
            </td></tr>

            </tbody></table>
        </td>
```

I want to hide 4th row of above table. the input contrains ID but somehow it is not working

```
<tr><td>
                <input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$UploadDocumentSection$ctl05$OverwriteSingle" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_OverwriteSingle" type="checkbox" checked="checked"><label for="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_OverwriteSingle">Overwrite existing files</label>
            </td></tr>
```

Comment: You forgot to show us the actual code that you say isn't working.

Comment: While I don't know how the rest of your code looks like, I would suggest you to try: `table.ms-authoringcontrols tr:nth-child(4){ ... }`

Comment: @Ofir Baruch: Why is jQuery necessary?

Comment: My bad, just woke up

Comment: I tried to use above Jquery. but I cannot add Jquery to page because it is sharepoint page. Can we add jquery to sharepointpoint popup on the fly ?

Comment: I rewrite the code, I used jQuery by mistake, there's no need in jQuery since it's a pure css solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 .ms-authoringcontrols tr:nth-child(4) {
        display: none;
    }
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/ZXjWV/40/)**

Comment: there are other tables also. this will hide 4th row of all tables

Answer (score 0):

Just Use `nth-child(4)` selector with `tr` tag. example is given below.

```
tr:nth-child(4) {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If this row will always be last, you can choose to hide the last row (check the code snippet).

if it will always be the fourth row you can change the css to:

```
.ms-authoringcontrols:nth-child(4) {
  display: none;
}
```

```css
.ms-authoringcontrols:nth-last-child(1) {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<td width="99%" class="ms-authoringcontrols">
            <table width="100%" class="ms-authoringcontrols">
            <tbody><tr><td>
                <input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$UploadDocumentSection$ctl05$InputFile" title="Choose a file" class="ms-fileinput ms-fullWidth" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_InputFile" onfocus="ResetSpFormOnSubmitCalled();" onchange="CheckAssetLibMediaExtension()" type="file" size="35">
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
                <span class="ms-error" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_ctl00" style="display: none;"><span role="alert">You must specify a value for the required field.</span></span>
                <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_ctl01" style="display: none;">The file name is invalid or the file is empty. A file name cannot contain any of the following characters: \ / : * ? " &lt; &gt; | # { } % ~ &amp;</span>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
                <a id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_OpenWithExplorerLink" accesskey="E" onclick="javascript:return !LaunchOpenInExplorer();" href="#">Upload files using Windows Explorer instead</a>
            </td></tr>

            <tr><td>
                <input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$UploadDocumentSection$ctl05$OverwriteSingle" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_OverwriteSingle" type="checkbox" checked="checked"><label for="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_UploadDocumentSection_ctl05_OverwriteSingle">Overwrite existing files</label>
            </td></tr>

            </tbody></table>
        </td>
```

Comment: yes this is always the 4th row. but it is opening in sharepoint popup. somehow the above css is not working. 
I can only add code to calling page.